# Streaming the results of multiple fs.readfiles

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm a newbie at node js streams, and what I want to achieve is streaming the results of the readfiles in a module that I have. I want to then somehow invoke this readable stream in my main app and listen to data events, so everytime readfile returns a result a data event will trigger, and the object is passed as a chunk. This is what I've got so far and it's throwing an error...

```
function streamObjects(type, dirname){
    var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
    var rs = new Readable({objectMode: true});
    fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, files){

        if(err)
            console.log(err);

        for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
        {           
            fs.readFile(path.resolve(dirname, files[i]),function(err,data){
                    if(err)
                        console.log(err);

                    rs.push(JSON.parse(data));
            }); //end readFile 
        } //end for loop
        return rs;
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use **EventEmitter**. 
Your readFile is an async function which is not called when you return **rs** Readable.

```
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function streamObjects(type, dirname) {
    var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
    var rs = new Readable({objectMode: true});
    var self = this;
    fs.readdir(dirname, function (err, files) {

    if (err)
        console.log(err);

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fs.readFile(path.resolve(dirname, files[i]), function (err, data) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            self.emit('data', files[i], data);
            rs.push(JSON.parse(data));
        }); //end readFile
    } //end for loop


  });
}

util.inherits(streamObjects, EventEmitter);


module.exports = streamObjects;
```

From another file

```
var streamObjects = require('streamObjects');

var streamObjectInstance = new streamObjects(type, dirName);
streamObjectInstance.on('data', yourFunctionHere);
```

I did not put into error emit, but you can add those to when error happens.